# How to convert Postgres from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to convert from PG 32 bit to 64 bit. I am testing with `pg_upgrade` (in several scenarios) but I think it cannot do that.

With `pg_upgrade`, I can upgrade PG version 8.5 to v.9 (both of them run in 32 bit or  64 bit).

Until now, I haven't found how to change from a 32 bit install to 64 bit. How can this be done?

Comment: There is no PG version 8.5... +D

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `pg_upgrade` for this, as it can only upgrade clusters from versions that are built with the same options on the same architecture. You must either:

- dump and reload, with the associated down-time; or
- Run both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions concurrently and set up a [3rd party replication tool](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) like Bucardo, Londiste or Slony-I to stream rows across. Once they're in sync, stop the 32-bit DB and remove the replication.

Also, there's no PostgreSQL 8.5. Did you mean 8.4? "v9" isn't very specific either - PostgreSQL 9.0, 9.1, and 9.2 are all quite distinct releases. See the [version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), which outlines PostgreSQL's quirky versioning.

Comment: @LuanHuynh I'm not sure I understand. If that helped, please accept the answer with the green tick. If not, please explain further.

Comment: Another "replication" option would be to pipe the output of pg_dump from the 32bit version to the 64bit version (although that does require to stop all write transactions on the source).

Comment: @CraigRinger: you know, I have two computers: one is running centos 32bit & installed PG 9.0, another isred hat 64bit & installed PG 9.1 . I used pg_dump to dump data from 32bit and copy-paste to 64bits (of course, two database is the same structure). But, with replication, I haven't tested yet, because I dont know three tools you listed, I am researching.