# How to install Slony for 64-bit PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.3, slony

I have installed 64-bit version of PostgreSQL 9.3.5 from EnterpriseDB installer. Now I want to install Slony-I through Application Stack Builder, but it offers only 32-bit version of Slony, incompatible with 64-bit PostgreSQL. My OS in Windows 7 64-bit.

Is there any easy way how to install it? Or do I have to build it from source? Or is there no way to do it except for [move to 32-bit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/45010/22006)?

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I posted a link to my compiled Slony 2.2.4 for Windows 64-bit under postgres 9.3.6. However, it was deleted I'm assuming because people may not trust my compile. Hence, here's the link to the Slony-I site with the instructions that I followed to compile Slony.

It's section 3.1.6. Building on Win32

http://www.slony.info/documentation/2.2/administration.html#BUILDINGWIN32

Comment: I may miss something, but section 3.1.6 in the link doesn't seem to help in installing Slony for 64-bit PostgreSQL. Doesn't Win32 refer to 32bit apps? The question wasn't about using Slony with any PostgreSQL 9.x on Windows 64-bit, but about using Slony with 64-bit PostgreSQL. Is this really what you did? If not, there are easier ways (EnterpriseDB installers of PostgreSQL 32bit work on Windows 64bit quite well).

Comment: I'm using Slony with my 64-bit postgres on Windows. I actually have one setup from Windows to Windows and one from Windows to Linux. They are all running on 64-bit postgres.

As for your question, you need to compile the proper files, rename them and copy them into the proper folder as directed at the end of section 3.1.6. This is like a manual install.